# How to achieve this replacement by `sed` or other command?

Tags: shell, sed

Here is the example text:

```
abc_fgh
abc_edg_pkl
abc_plc
abc_action
there are some other texts in the file
not at begin  abc_action
abc_nmp
```

How to replace the text begin with `abc_` to `efg_`, **and** `abc_action` should not be modified?

That is to say, for the example text above, the output should be:

```
efg_fgh
efg_edg_pkl
efg_plc
abc_action
there are some other texts in the file
not at begin  abc_action
efg_nmp
```

Every word begin with `abc_` is not meaningful except `abc_action`, which should not be modified.

Every word begin with `abc_` except `abc_action` should be modified to the word begin with efg_.

I can't guarantee that `abc_` is at the begin of the line.

How to achieve this goal by `sed` or other command?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/^abc_action$/!s/^abc_/efg_/'
```

Which means *on lines not containing `abc_actions` and nothing else, replace the leading `abc_` with `efg_`.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English. I may mislead you. I can't guarantee that `abc_` is at the begin of the line. So, it seems that there should not `^` in the `sed '/^abc_action$/!s/^abc_/efg_/'`. Am I right? I updated my post to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

- if you don't want to modify the line with `abc_action`:

```
sed '/abc_action/!s/\([ ]\+\)abc_\|^abc_/\1efg_/g' filename
```

- if you want to modify the line with `abc_action`, there is a trick to change  `abc_action` to a special word or sign(here as `#`) which will not be replaced the `abc_` pattern, then modify `abc_` pattern and recovery the `abc_action` last.

```
sed 's/abc_action/#/g' filename | sed 's/\([ ]\+\)abc_\|^abc_/\1efg_/g' | sed 's/#/abc_action/g'
```

explicate:

1, `/abc_action/!`: `sed` will not handle the lines which contain `abc_action`.

2, `s/regexp/replacement/g`: replace all `regexp` to `replacement` each line.

3, `s/\([ ]\+\)abc_\|^abc_/\1efg_/g`: will replace the word which start with  `abc_` or at the begin of the line as `abc_` to `efg_`. I guess that the word which not at the begin of the line should be split by one or more blank.

4, `\([ ]\+\)`: the one or more blank space pattern.

5, `\1`: will copy the pattern getting of the blank space in result.

Comment: Any difference between *the word which start with  `abc_`* between *at the begin of the line as abc_`*? I think the former one includes the latter one. Am I right?

Comment: @John `\([ ]\+\)` this pattern only match the word begin with one or more blank place and `abc_` which present  in the middle of line but not at the begin of the line. Such as `abc_nmp abc_nmp` this line, `\([ ]\+\)abc_\|^abc_` this pattern will match.

Answer (score 0):

A Perl solution:

```
perl -lpe 's{abc_(?!action)}{efg_}g; ' in_file > out_file
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`(?!action)` : negative lookahead. It means that the following string **cannot** match `action`.

The regex uses these modifier:
`/g` : Match the pattern repeatedly.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)